# String mode policy logs now showing anything related to my code

Tags: android, performance, crash, android-anr-dialog, android-strictmode

I recently started receiving constant ANR messages in my app.
I am unable to find out what's causing them.
I enabled StrictModePolicty but the logs (shown below) don't indicate anything related to my code. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=97 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:144)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:225)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.startFrameMonitoring(AppStateMonitor.java:157)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityCreated(AppStateMonitor.java:174)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:387)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityCreated(Activity.java:1419)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1701)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:86)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:379)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:216)
    at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:60)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=95 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:204)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkVersionDisabled(ConfigResolver.java:256)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.startFrameMonitoring(AppStateMonitor.java:157)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityCreated(AppStateMonitor.java:174)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:387)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityCreated(Activity.java:1419)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1701)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:86)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:379)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:216)
    at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:60)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=51 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:144)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:225)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityStarted(AppStateMonitor.java:192)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:420)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityStarted(Activity.java:1451)
    at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1969)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:344)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1510)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4204)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=49 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:204)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkVersionDisabled(ConfigResolver.java:256)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityStarted(AppStateMonitor.java:192)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:420)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityStarted(Activity.java:1451)
    at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1969)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:344)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1510)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4204)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=47 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:144)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:225)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.start(Trace.java:209)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityStarted(AppStateMonitor.java:202)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:420)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityStarted(Activity.java:1451)
    at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1969)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:344)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1510)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4204)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=46 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1658)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:74)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:8610)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.isSpeg(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:505)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:517)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.DeviceCacheManager.setValue(DeviceCacheManager.java:204)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsSdkVersionDisabled(ConfigResolver.java:256)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getIsServiceCollectionEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:199)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.isPerformanceMonitoringEnabled(ConfigResolver.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.start(Trace.java:209)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityStarted(AppStateMonitor.java:202)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:420)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityStarted(Activity.java:1451)
    at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1969)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:344)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1510)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4204)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```